# Find out if an Python object is callable

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find out if an object is callable or not.

I know that `type()` would return `<class 'method'>`. But I don't know how I can check for that (e.g. with `isinstance()`).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the builtin [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable):

```
>>> callable(open)
True
>>> print(callable.__doc__)
callable(object) -> bool

Return whether the object is callable (i.e., some kind of function).
Note that classes are callable, as are instances with a __call__() method.
```

It's a great investment making an effort to master at least 90% of the builtin functions listed here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 24):

If you must use `isinstance`, you may check against [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) (Python ≥ 3.5):

```
from typing import Callable
obj = lambda x: x + 1
isinstance(obj, Callable)
>>> True
obj = 42
isinstance(obj, Callable)
>>> False
```