# python make sure () aren't passed in parameter

Tags: python

I have a function that works fine if `()` isn't used in the function name:

```py
answer = message.AskQuestion(
    self.loc_top, thread=self.refresh_play_top, align='left',
    icon='warning', title="Forget Location Confirmation", text=text)
```

If I use `()` by accident, E.G. `thread=self.refresh_play_top()`, the function returns corrupt data:

```py
answer = message.AskQuestion(
    self.loc_top, thread=self.refresh_play_top(), align='left',
    icon='warning', title="Forget Location Confirmation", text=text)
```

Inside the `.AskQuestion()` function, there is this:

```py
self.thread = thread        # The thread run before button click
```

How could this be changed?

---

### Solution

Using the accepted answer:

- Change `self.refresh_play_top()` function to always return `True` or `False` including function end which returns `None` by default.
- Add 7 lines of code to `AskQuestion()` function (shown at bottom):

```py
    def __init__(self, parent, text=None, confirm='yes',
                 align='center', thread=None, icon='warning'):

        self.top_level = parent     # Allows .after() calls
        self.confirm = confirm      # Append "Are you sure?" line?
        self.align = align          # data (text lines) alignment
        if thread is None:
            self.thread = None
        elif callable(thread):
            self.thread = thread    # The thread run before button click
        else:
            print("message.py, CommonSelf, invalid thread= passed")
            self.thread = None
```

- Test, fix, test, fix, text, fix :)

Thanks to the experts who promptly commented and answered.

Comment: Use type hints to indicate that the `thread` argument should be a `Callable`. Then your IDE or a type checker like `mypy` will warn you if you call it incorrectly.

Comment: You can go further than that. That's static type checking; you can check it at runtime e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505019/4799172

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out if an Python object is callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004766/find-out-if-an-python-object-is-callable)

Comment: @Barmar I use PyCharm but not that feature yet. Thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh Yes and No. I've edited the question with the solution. Please advise if I should close as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever have the `()` at the end of thing, python will try to call that thing. So when you have `thread=self.refresh_play_top()`, python will call the function `refresh_play_top`, and that function will return something - either None or something that isn't None. Then that returned object is what gets passed to your `message.AskQuestion(...)`. So if `self.refresh_play_top()` returns 5, you are effectively doing `thread=5`. Any attempt to get your script to let you pass the return-value of the function (that, with the `()`) instead of the function itself will cause more problems.

As some folks put in the comments, there are typecheckers that can help you catch this as you are writing your code and to help you avoid the mistake. That is a much better idea than trying to shoe-horn into the program some code to let you write the code wrong but still do what you want.

Comment: `self.refresh_play_top()` doesn't return anything. It just spins album artwork every 33 miiseconds while `ffplay` plays a song in a separate shell job. The `thread=` parameter is called whilst waiting for User to click "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Every function that terminates returns *something*, even if only `None`. The call to `AskQuestion` will block until `refresh_play_top` returns.

Comment: @chepner `refresh_play_top` returns after a millisecond or two because it is called within a 33 millisecond (30 fps (frames per second)) idle loop. `thread=None` is already a valid parameter so `refresh_play_top` returning `None` is a deal breaker. So I changed the half dozen `return` commands to return True or False (including the last line) and everything works now.