# MyPy complains about isinstance(obj, Callable) being incompatible with _ClassInfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I've got a couple of `if`s that all use `isinstance`. One of them is checking the `obj` against `Collable` with `isinstance(obj, Callable)` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65505019/235671) answer. But when I run `mypy` on that code it reports the following error:

> ```
> error: Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "_ClassInfo"
> ```

Is there any way to fix that without using the builtin `callable` function or disabling type checking for this line?

Comment: Why would you not use the built-in `callable` function?  That's exactly what it's for.  `Callable` is a special typing thing that is not part of the class tree, as you can see.

Comment: @TimRoberts the `if`s look so nice and consistent when they all use the same pattern :-] Why does this actually even work when it's _just_ a typing hint? The answer in the other question has also quite a few upvotes so it can't be entirely wrong, can it?

Comment: Does this even work? In any case, `typing.Callable` is deprecated. Use `collections.abc.Callable`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it works. As you can see in the other question it returns `True` for a lambda and I also have unit-tests for my code where it also works and I test it with `def`s and _callable_ classes. That's why I'm surprised that mypy is confused.

Comment: Well, the consistency is misleading. Fundamentally, `Callable` isn't a real type. `collections.abc.Callable` is an abc, so it reliesnon "virtual subclassing". Using `callable` is the pythonic way,

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm surprised it ever worked. In any case, it's deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use `collections.abc.Callable`

Comment: The docs state that the `Callable` in the `typing` is a dephricated alias to `collections.abc.Callable`. Maybe that's why it works? Mhmm...

Comment: `isinstance(<object>, collections.abc.Callable)` has the same mypy issue. Neither `typing.Callable` nor `collections.abc.Callable` is accepted by mypy as the second argument for `isinstance`. I would avoid doing this and just use `callable(<object>)`, or if you really need to do this, use `@typing.runtime_checkable` on a callback `typing.Protocol`.

Comment: @dROOOze then that sounds like a real mypy bug. What does pyright give?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga pyright is permissive to the point of a false negative. `isinstance(<object>, Callable)` works at runtime, and `isinstance(<object>, Callable[[<arguments>], <return>])` fails at runtime. mypy rejects both, [pyright accepts both](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIAAAROGUC_3WNsQrDMAxEd3-FoEsLodC1W-lnmA62cFIVRTKWFv99Am0zBLId7x53J6i90fT2O5g3Qg9hbDqD90oyAc1Vm8ND-hejMhd0UrFryvjvn4k5ZS4hkJGYJ8Fyvg0bvxzwGDV_1r3XAL-wN9fnPWIyj5seFiKD3CXCAAAA).